# CSS Getting text to align properly in list with custom bullet

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get the text in my list to align properly, but I can't get it right.

[image]

As you can see the text is slightly off and starts at the "image bullet" baseline. I want it to be in the middle.

Source:

```
//CSS
ul  {
    list-style-image:url(image/li.png);
    list-style-position:outside;
    margin:0; padding:0;
}
ul li {
    margin:0; padding:0;
}

//HTML
<ul>
   <li>Item 1</li>
   <li>Item 2</li>
   <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Now define** your `li` **background image** and define `background position` according to **your design**

```
ul  {
    list-style:none;
     margin:0; padding:0;
}
ul li {
    margin:0; padding:0;
  background:url('') no-repeat 0 0;
  padding-left:40px;  // according to your image with
  min-height:40px; // according to your image height
}
```

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/vU0g3iCF)***

[**DEMO2**](http://tinkerbin.com/pX8ZYIgh) **As per OP's exact requirement**

Comment: Great, yes, found this link aswell http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listutorial/master.htm

Comment: @jamietelin please see the updated answer i hope you are looking like this exactly......

Answer (score 4):

you have to set the line-height property of the li elements to be the same as the height of the custom icon.

For example if your icon has an height of 32px, you should write:

```
ul li {
  line-height: 32px;
}
```

Better use an id to identify the ul element, otherwise you may end up affecting all the ul in the document.